# SET the value of a Shopify Option Selector / change selected variant via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I am building a custom "subscription builder" where customers select options, proceed to the next step and at the end click checkout; their options reflected in the variant selected.

The way Im going about this is by hiding shopify's selectors and setting them manually using $().val(); This accurately changes the selectors (checking in inspector), but Shopify does not recognize these changes for some reason and so the product added to the cart is the default. I am obviously missing something - is this even possible?

[Code Redacted for uselessness]

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the page code here?

Comment: Shopify is most likely sending data to the server and getting a response back. You're going to have to edit the back-end code as well.

Comment: While it does _not_ send a request or anything, it does use their javascript to structure the "product form." I posted an answer detailing how you can do it.

Comment: With your original code, `$(element).val(newValue).trigger('change');` should have also triggered all of the code needed to update everything properly, but the solution that you arrived at takes better advantage of Shopify's functionality. :)

Comment: Oh awesome! Thanks - I didn't even think of using that. Now that I have the robust variant id finder its much more robust this way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically,

Shopify's option_selection.js controls this and has a "Product" and "OptionSelector" object.

OptionSelector has a function selectVariant(id, selector) that will properly set it given you have the full variant identifier.

In your product_form.liquid you will see a place that does new OptionSelector(args). You simply save what it returns, i.e.

```
selector = new OptionSelector(...);
```

then you can do

```
selector.selectVariant("123456789", selector);
```

This will properly set the variant for the checkout button. You can then either hide the 'shopify' selectors with css / js or keep them or modify the option_selection.js code yourself by downloading from [here](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/shopify/option_selection.js).

Furthermore, I've discovered more useful things one can do:

```
selector.selectors[index].element.value {get; set;} //much cleaner method of accessing selector elements 
selector.product.getVariant(selector.selectedValues()).id // gets the variant id for you so you do not need to hardcore them in
```

EDIT: Dave has kindly pointed out that

```
$(element).val(newValue).trigger('change');
```

Would have done what I wanted, but points out (and I agree) that using OptionSelector is more of a robust method.